# Constraintlayout does not behave well as recyclerview 's item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview whose items look like this:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_food_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_food_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <com.mikhaellopez.circleview.CircleView
            android:id="@+id/food_image"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:cv_color="@color/colorAccent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/food_contents"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/food_title_homepage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:fontFamily="@font/sans_regular"
                android:text="عنوان غذا"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ingredients_homepage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:fontFamily="@font/sans_regular"
                android:text="مواد اولیه"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I'm trying to convert this into a flat hierarchy using Constraintlayout.
Here's how it looks:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_food_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_food_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/food_title_homepage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="عنوان غذا"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/food_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ingredients_homepage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="مواد اولیه"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/food_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/food_title_homepage" />

        <com.mikhaellopez.circleview.CircleView
            android:id="@+id/food_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            app:cv_color="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Here's where my Recyclerview is inserted:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".main.homepage.HomepageFragment">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/homepage_progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recipes"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/homepage_toolbar"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_homepage_food_item" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/homepage_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/fragment_homepage_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's how each item should be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcfAm.png

But I don't get the same results in the Recyclerview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpUG4.png

I didn't have the problem before I converted the view into Constraintlayout!! Everything was working just fine until now that I converted them. They all become left-aligned in the Recyclerview!!

Does anyone know what the problem is?? Thanks in advance

-- **Updated** --

How it looks like on an android emulator or any other devices: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvGz4.png

When I scroll down to the bottom (I update the list after each scroll) some items become right-aligned (they somehow get fixed) but the rest stays the same (still left aligned)

-- **Java Code** --

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomepageViewModel.class);

getData(0);

setRecyclerView(linearLayoutManager);

EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener scrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
    @Override
    public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
        getData(page);
    }
};
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
```

```
private void getData(int offset) {
    viewModel.init(this, offset);
    viewModel.getFoodsLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), foodList -> {
        if (foodList != null) {
            foods.addAll(foodList);
            foodList.clear();
            foodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

private void setRecyclerView(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
    foodAdapter = new FoodAdapter(foods);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(foodAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
}
```

My adapter:

```
private void getData(int offset) {
    viewModel.init(this, offset);
    viewModel.getFoodsLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), foodList -> {
        if (foodList != null) {
            foods.addAll(foodList);
            foodList.clear();
            foodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

private void setRecyclerView(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
    foodAdapter = new FoodAdapter(foods);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(foodAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
}
My adapter:

private List<Food> foods;

    FoodAdapter(List<Food> foods) {
        this.foods = foods;
    }

    static class FoodViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CircleView foodImage;
        TextView foodTitle, ingredients;
        CardView foodItem;

        FoodViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            foodImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_image);
            foodTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_title_homepage);
            ingredients = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ingredients_homepage);
            foodItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_food_item);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FoodViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_homepage_food_item, parent, false);
        return new FoodViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FoodViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Food currentFood = foods.get(position);
        
        
        StringBuilder food_ingredient_str = new StringBuilder();
        int ingredient_position = 0;
        int ingredients_size = currentFood.getFood_ingredients().size();
        for (Food.FoodIngredient foodIngredient : currentFood.getFood_ingredients()) {
            food_ingredient_str.append(foodIngredient.getIngredient());
            if (ingredient_position != ingredients_size / 3)
                food_ingredient_str.append(", ");
            if (ingredient_position == ingredients_size / 3) {
                food_ingredient_str.append(" و ...");
                break;
            }
            ingredient_position += 1;
        }

        holder.foodTitle.setText(currentFood.getName());
        holder.ingredients.setText(food_ingredient_str);

        holder.foodItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("current_food", currentFood);
                Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.action_navigation_home_to_navigation_food, bundle);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return foods.size();
    }
```

Comment: Is this happens only in Editor or on a device too?

Comment: I get stranger results on my device. Let me share it with you. @hardartcore

Comment: @hardartcore --  I just updated the post

Comment: Maybe there iare conflicts with your device's Locale. Can you share that info too?

Comment: Maybe you are not dealing with the java code properly. Can you share it here?

Comment: @hardartcore -- How can I share it?

Comment: @FaisalKhan  -- I will right away. Though I don't think that would be the problem. Everything were working just fine before converting to Constraintlayout.

Comment: @Mehrkish Araste Edit the question and put your java adapter codes. That doesn't matter it was working fine previously... new changes may need more new changes

Comment: @FaisalKhan -- Why do think it becomes left-aligned in the editor? Could it be due to Android Studio's bug or anything?? The editor was working just fine though when I was using Linearlayout instead of Constraintlayout.

Comment: Why would the editor misfunction when using Constraintlayout?

Comment: @Mehrkish Araste you wrote done... is it solved now? If you think it is the editor which malfunctioned then it is usual for the latest version of android studio to have some bugs. Later it is fixed...

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to create a list using recyclerview and each item to be right aligned as in Arabic.. then try these approaches**

### replace your "recycle_view_item_layout.xml" with this

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_food_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_food_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/food_contents"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/food_title_homepage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sans_regular"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="عنوان غذا"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ingredients_homepage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sans_regular"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="مواد اولیه"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.mikhaellopez.circleview.CircleView
        android:id="@+id/food_image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:cv_color="@color/colorAccent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

### replace your "recycle view" with this

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recipes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/homepage_toolbar"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_homepage_food_item" />
```

### and attach a layout manager like this (important)

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

setRecyclerView(layoutManager);
```

**and rest of your code seems okay**